# Find the size of directory in unix

Tags: linux, unix

**Problem Statement:-**

I am getting this below exception-

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DSQuotaExceededException:
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DSQuotaExceededException: The DiskSpace 
quota of /tmp is exceeded: quota=659706976665600 diskspace consumed=614400.1g
```

So I just wanted to know how much is the size of /tmp directory currently and because of that I am getting this exception. How can I see the free space in /tmp?

**Update:-**

```
bash-3.00$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
rpool/tmp               10G   2.2G   7.8G    22%    /tmp
```

I am puzzled right now why I am getting that exception then as it clearly states above that I have space available.

Comment: `quota=659706976665600 diskspace consumed=614400.1g`

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry I am not that much familiar with unix. Can you explain me what does that line means?

Comment: I believe the `quota` is how much space you're allotted and `diskspace consumed` is how much you've used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do (For SunOS)

```
# du -sh /tmp
```

To see how much it uses now, but that you already saw.

To see how much total, free and used space is on the partition where `/tmp` resides you can use:

```
# df -h /tmp
```

Note that filling up space is not the only thing that can prevent writing to filesystem.

Running out of inodes is another popular reason.

You can check that with

```
# df -i /tmp
```

Comment: I got this error when I tried executing first command you gave me. `bash-3.00$ du -sxh /tmp
du: illegal option -- x
usage: du [-a] [-d] [-h|-k] [-r] [-o|-s] [-H|-L] [file ...]
`.

Comment: And with the third command you gave me, I am getting this exception- `bash-3.00$ df -i /tmp
df: unknown option: i
Usage: df [-F FSType] [-abeghklntVvZ] [-o FSType-specific_options] [directory | block_device | resource]
`.

Comment: Ok, apparently your system uses some unorthodox `du` version :), just ditch the `x` :)

Comment: Which OS are you using? I was basing my answer on Linux, if you specify the OS I can give you the commands that will work on yours.

Comment: Figures. Ok, forget the inodes part. And remove the `x` from the `du` example, so make it `du -sh /tmp`.

Comment: So with the second command, I got this- `bash-3.00$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
rpool/tmp               10G   2.2G   7.8G    22%    /tmp
`. Then I am puzzled why I got that exception and it is showing I have space available in /tmp?

Comment: Apparently you have quota's enabled and quota for the current user has been exceeded. I'd recommend talking to your neighborhood sysadmin to get this resolved. It would be a bit difficult to explain how to change that and will largely depend on the solutions chosen for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

for a in `ls`; do du -ch ${a} | grep  total ; echo ${a}; done

try this but it takes time if the size of dir is in GBs

Answer (score 0):

Managing HDFS Space Quotas
It’s important to understand that in HDFS, there must be enough quota space to accommodate an entire block. If the user has, let’s say, 200MB free in their allocated quota, they can’t create a new file, regardless of the file size, if the HDFS block size happens to be 256MB. You can set the HDFS space quota for a user by executing the setSpace-Quota command. Here’s the syntax:

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin –setSpaceQuota <N> <dirname>...<dirname>
```

The space quota you set acts as the ceiling on the total size of all files in a directory. You can set the space quota in bytes (b), megabytes (m), gigabytes (g), terabytes (t) and even petabytes (by specifying p—yes, this is big data!). And here’s an example that shows how to set a user’s space quota to 60GB:

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 60G /user/alapati
```

You can set quotas on multiple directories at a time, as shown here:

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 10g /user/alapati /test/alapati
```